# Screwdriver for changing HDD and PCI cards on Dell Vostro

Tags: upgrade, dell-vostro

I have a Dell Vostro 400 and the Dell site has no information at all on which screwdrivers are suitable for taking out the hard drive and PCI cards.

I am sure users on here do a lot of work with hardware upgrades on their pc. Is there any recommended screwdriver set which would likely work with the screws in the hard drive and PCI slots (I can't get sizing info on these)?

EDIT: This is Dell's PC, not laptop.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

[Phillips](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henry_F._Phillips) #1 and #2, and a set of [TORX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torx) bits will pretty much let you disassemble any PC/Laptop. A set of small flatheads may be useful as well for prying, Laptops in particular can be held together with clips on the inside that require some careful prying to get apart.

Amazon has some [computer tool kits](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_ss?url=search-alias%3Daps&field-keywords=computer+tool+kit&x=0&y=0), but you can also pick this stuff up at your local hardware store. Phillips screwdrivers (the "plus" head) are available basically anywhere, they are the most common type of screw in the world.

Comment: Do you have any links to the relevant products?

Answer (score 0):

I just took the case off of my Vostro 420, and they're just regular computer screws.

Any screwdriver that fits should work, just make sure the computer is off and avoid magnetized screwdrivers (even though they really don't do anything unless you touch the board with them).

Comment: The screws on the case (Black ones) I can take off with my hands.

Comment: BTW the problem is I don't how to find a screwdriver which will fit!

Comment: I don't think "regular computer screws" tells him what size and type screwdriver to buy.

Comment: Go with that Phillips #1 or #2 gregmac mentioned. I don't know what screwdriver I've used in the past- if it unscrews it, it works. Grab a set from the toolbox and stick a few in the slots. Whichever one unscrews first is your winner.

Answer (score 0):

I use one of these and it works great.  very solid and has all the most common sizes in one unit.

[15-1 Screwdriver](http://www.leevalley.com/wood/page.aspx?c=1&p=40859&cat=1,43411,43417&ap=2)

For really small stuff this is really good.  Great for Blackberries similar

[MicroDriver](http://www.leevalley.com/wood/page.aspx?c=1&p=61117&cat=1,43411,43417&ap=1)